# OneDrive saving problems

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-office, onedrive, microsoft-office-2013

I'm not sure what they've changed but saving Office 2013 documents will usually default to my OneDrive folder. But for some reason, it now defaults to some web address and not my local OneDrive folder. This is in the "Save as" window and I can't post a screenshot.

So what happens now is that when I save a file, it saves to that web address and the file appears as "online only" in my OneDrive folder. I also noticed the folder's name is "SkyDrive" as I had it installed long before I upgraded to Windows 8.1. Is this the problem? I have two drives so I changed the default save location when I installed the then SkyDrive client. I never had issues with it until now.

I don't notice this issue on my laptop with Windows 7. Saving into my OneDrive folder saves it to C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents instead of a web address.